# Nuclear Shell Models: Extreme single particle Vs Single particle

Tags: nuclear-physics

What is the difference between extreme single particle shell model and single particle shell model? Why the spin for odd-even, even-odd, even-even nuclei are same in both the models, but odd-odd nuclei are treated only in single particle shell model by using the Nordheim rule?